# Codeigniter - how to include a dynamic javascript file in a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to include the following code block (which contains some dynamic values) in my header view if certain conditions are met.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/jquery.Jcrop.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if (isset($load_jcrop_api) && $load_jcrop_api === TRUE) {?>
        // Javascript 1
    <?php } else { ?>
        // Javascript 2
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

I've done some reading up and I started to try the following but I get an error trying to call this function from within a view so I'm a bit stuck on the best way to appoach this.

CONTROLLER

```
function get_jcrop_ini() {
    $this->output->set_header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    $data = array( 'messages' => $this->session->flashdata('message'));
    $this->load->view('jcrop_ini',$data);
}
```

VIEW

```
if (isset($load_jcrop) && $load_jcrop === TRUE) {
    $this->get_jcrop_ini();
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Can you place it here please?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_Loader::get_jcrop_ini() in C:\inetpub\d..\application\views\includes\header.php on line 81

Comment: That is simple then... controller methods are not passed over to the view! You can create a helper function in the application/helpers/ folder that can be called in the view!

Comment: I've created and loaded a helper but I get errors using $this in the helper. 
function get_jcrop_ini() {
 $this->output->set_header('Content-type: text/javascript');
 $data['load_jcrop_api'] = FALSE;
 $this->load->view('jcrop_ini',$data);
}

Comment: I wrote a snippet to embed JavaScript files an internal code into views and manqging them inside of controllers. It could be helpful: https://gist.github.com/HashemQolami/5994689

Comment: You can't call $this-> in the helper function! Write the code as scripting, not OO.

Comment: So how to I use a helper to output the javascript code block? I could echo from the controller but that doesn't seem sensible. I need to pass data to a view and get the output back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the JS view in the controller and pass it over to the controller.

`$jsview = $this->load->view('view_name', array(), true);`

Note that the third parameter is set to true. That will return the view to you instead of outputting the view to the screen.

Then, pass it over to your main view.

```
$data['js'] = $jsview;

$this->load->view('mainview',$data);
```

That is a better MVC approach as the logic remains in the controller.

Comment: I'm familiar with that technique and having given it more thought I think that will work fine for me. Thanks!