# How do I use this seemingly simple loop in CodeIgniter's view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the **view**, right before the footer, I want to load three JavaScript files.  So, the controller sets three variables. For example, $js_1 = "bootstrap.js", $js_2 = '' and $js_3 = "tinymce.js", which may or may not be empty. The logic is, it should echo only if the variable is not empty. I also want to use the **ternary if operator**.

This was the best I could try.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    echo (!empty ('$js_' . $i)) ? get_jscript('$js_' . $i) : NULL;
}
```

The function get_jscript() simply returns the HTML script src.

```
function get_jscript($js) 
{
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $js . '"></script> ';
}
```

Please note that I intend to ask this question to primarily learn the correct PHP syntax and not just load JS in the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - how to include a dynamic javascript file in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952185/codeigniter-how-to-include-a-dynamic-javascript-file-in-a-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) has some great info on how to use variable variables.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    echo (!empty (${'js_'.$i})) ? get_jscript(${'js_'.$i}) : NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you can create a array like this->

```
$javascript = array('js_1' => "bootstrap.js", 'js_2' => '', 'js_3' = "tinymce.js");
```

then in your view you have to just call a method

```
loop_javascript($javascript);
```

it's better to create a function in codeigniter helper and call that helper in controller's function (check how to use helpers in codeingiter) https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html->

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('loop_javascript'))
{
    function loop_javascript($jscript_array)
    {
        foreach($jscript_array as $key =>$value){
            if($value != ''){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $value. '"></script>';
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    if(!empty($js.'_'.$i)){ echo get_jscript($js.'_'.$i); echo "</br>";}
}

function get_jscript($js) 
{
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $js . '"></script> ';
}
```

Comment: No, mate. That doesn't work because looping that way would make $js a variable which does not exist. And clearly, since I want to load the JavaScript files, I'm doing it in the head or foot; which means no line breaks.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @VivekGhimire i'm concatenating the value of  `$i` with `$js` => `$js.'_'.$i`, so it give us the variables `$js_1`,`$js_2`,`$js_3`.. and you can use `\n\r` insted of `</br>`

Comment: Dear @Hatchet, Thank you so much for the appreciation, i'll take care of these things in future and try to explain as much i can ...

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala, Thanks. I'll look upon them.